# Tikz floor function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to floor a number whilst drawing something... simple as that really: `2*\pi*\floor(1.5)`

I've tried looking for it online but all I get is people trying to plot graphs using the floor function but I simply just want to get 1 from 1.5 or 2 from 2.5 when I don't actually know the value so something like

```
\floor(\s)
```

I have tried using `floor(1.5)` e.g.:

```
\draw (0,0)--(floor(1.5),1);
```

But I get `error package pgf error no shape named floor(1 is known.`

Comment: As always on the site, you are much much mnore likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test. Right now your question is more like a `please do this for me` which is not suitable for a Q&A site

Comment: `floor` is a built-in function (and you could use `int` instead). But the question is not too clear to me. Of course, if you use pgf functions, you shouldn't use backslashes, but e.g. `2*pi*floor(1.5)`.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat I have tried doing floor(1.5) and I get errors such as package pgf error: no shape named floor(1 is known.

Comment: You need to parse the expression. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
The floor of $1.257$ is
$\pgfmathparse{floor(1.257)}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$.
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\draw` call using `pgfmath`'s `floor()` function can be very simply done, because Ti*k*Z coordinates are automatically parsed with `\pgfmathparse`. The only problem with what you tried is due to the parentheses after `floor`, which confuse the Ti*k*Z parser when it is reading the coordinates of a point (Ti*k*Z will consider that the first closing parenthesis marks the end of the point, unless it is “hidden” inside curly braces). Thus, if you wrap the expression for the *x* coordinate—the one that contains parentheses in your example—within curly braces, it works like a charm:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- ({floor(1.5)},1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you asked about values in a `\foreach` loop, here is an example using `\pgfmathsetmacro` to do the mathematical expression parsing:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\upperbound}{floor(10.5)}

\foreach \s in {1,2,...,\upperbound} {
  \draw (0,\s) -- (\s,0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Holy moly thank you so much!!! I swear to god I would have tried that lol.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work in a list such as {1,2,...,{floor(10.5)}} any idea why?

Comment: I lack the context. Is it a `\foreach` loop?

Comment: Yes the loop exactly I'm trying to do is: \foreach \s in {1,2,...,{floor(10.5)}}        I've even tried setting it as a command using \def\n{{floor(10.5}} and \newcommand\n{{floor(10.5)}}

Comment: IIRC, in this case you need to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` before the loop, then use the macro in the list of values. With `pgfplots`, there are other ways. Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: I have a big circle and on the radius of the circle I have little circles that are barely touching eachother and in order to get the amount of circles I can fit on the circles radius I need to do floor(2*pi*1/0.2) and then I need to do it again when I decrease the radius of the big circle so I basically have a sphere made up of little circles

Comment: That's fantastic thank you. Kind of infuriating that it works in coordinates but not lists tho

Comment: Yes, that's how it is... In `pgfplots` loop functions, the `pgfmath` parser is invoked if the `...` values start with two elements instead of only one. Useful, but not intuitive either! (`pgfplots` manual section *Utility Commands*, which is on page 542 in the manual for version 1.16; applies to `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` and `\pgfplotsforeach` unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: Thank you so much you have been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something as simple as this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
The floor of $1.257$ is
$\pgfmathparse{floor(1.257)}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect but is there any way of doing this without the extra library?

Comment: @OllyEatough In principle, yes, but you would have to write a rather involved function if you want to have the functionality of the pgf function, which you can find in `pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm just gonna give the docs index a quick look through to see if there is actually a floor function and im just using incorrect syntax.